# Delete joomla website and install wordpress on same domain

Tags: wordpress, joomla

i need to delete a joomla website and all its content and install a brand new wordpress website on the same domain.

My thought was:connecting via cpanel and find the joomla website domain via file manager and delete the whole folder thats in public_html.After it to upload -unzip wordpress on public_html and install it.

Can someone correct or maybe suggest a better way to do it?
Thank you.

Comment: you are right but before do anything take backup of your Joomla directory and database.

Comment: since i dont really need any of the old data i guess i shouldnt?

Comment: Ok then go ahead

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right path.
You'll also need to delete the old Joomla database and create a new one for Wordpress, using phpmyadmin.